# Derivative of log determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $x_i \in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $a_i\in [0,1]$ for $i = 1,\dots,k$. How to compute the following derivative?

$$
\frac{d}{da_j}\log \det\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k a_ix_ix_i^\top\right).
$$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{da_j}\log \det\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k a_ix_ix_i^\top\right)
\\ 
&= \frac1{\det\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k a_ix_ix_i^\top\right)}\det\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k a_ix_ix_i^\top\right)\operatorname{Tr}\left(\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k a_ix_ix_i^\top\right)^{-1}x_jx_j^\top\right)
\\&=
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k a_ix_ix_i^\top\right)^{-1}x_jx_j^\top\right)
\end{align*}
using $d \det(A)(X) = \operatorname{Tr}(\operatorname{adj}(A)X) = \det(A)\operatorname{Tr}(A^{-1}X)$.